# Read Double byte characters in plist from shell

Tags: macos, shell, plist

I am working on Mac. I have a p-list entry containing double byte chinese characters,

ie.ProductRoot  `/Users/labuser/Desktop/您好`.

Now i am running this command on terminal
 defaults read "path to p-list" ProductRoot
 and I am getting `/Users/labuser/Desktop/\u60a8\u597d`

........How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

"defaults read" doesn't seem to have any way to change the format of the output. Maybe you could pipe that to another command-line tool to unescape the Unicode characters.

Failing that, it'd be very easy to write a tool in Objective-C or Swift to dump just that one value as a string.

As a side note, you claim the file has double-byte characters. If it's being created by native Mac code, it's probably more-likely to be in UTF-8 encoding. I don't know if that would matter at all, but I figured I'd add that in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
defaults read | grep ppt | perl -npe 's/\\\\U(\w\w\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge'
```